# Can Bolt Psionic Power make bullets for guns?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

Can you use Bolt Psionic Power with a Marksman (Kaigun) Battered Gun?

Since Bolt is in the Marksman's powers list, can the power make phantom gunpowder ammunition?

Answer (score 3):

## No

[*Bolt*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/psionics-unleashed/psionic-powers/b/bolt/) states:

> **Effect** A normal bolt, arrow, or sling bullet

and additionally:

> You create 2d4 ectoplasmic crossbow bolts, arrows, or sling bullets...

both of which do not indicate the power has any ability to create ammunition for firearms.

Answer (score 2):

No. But you have two other options:

- [Energy](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/psionics-unleashed/equipment/psionic-items/psionic-weapons#TOC-Energy) Psionic Weapon enchantment (+12,000 gp), makes all your ammunition to be made of psionic energy and no longer require real ammo.
- The [Warsoul](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/psionics-unleashed/classes/soulknife/archetypes/dreamscarred-press/war-soul-soulknife-archetype/) (Soulknife Archetype, from *Path of War*) can create firearms of psionic energy (using the [Solar Wind](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/path-of-war/disciplines-and-maneuvers#TOC-Solar-Wind-Discipline) discipline) that fire psionic-generated ammunition. Two levels in the class should be enough to gain that ability.

An alternative is to have a chat with your GM to [research your own version of that power](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/psionics-unleashed/psionic-powers#TOC-Adding-Powers) that works exclusively with firearms, but should not work with bow, crossbow or sling ammunition.